# Acessar um objeto data frame, dentro de uma função no R - Censo 2010

Tags: r

Gostaria de carregar os arquivos do Censo 2010. Primeiramente estou carregando os domicílios, através de uma função, usando o comando `read_fwf`, do pacote `readr`. Porém, os data frames criados, ficam dentro do ambiente da minha função e eu gostaria de externalizá-los, de forma que tenha acesso no meu ambiente fora da função. Esta é a função que escrevi:

```
require(readr)

vetor_largura_domicilio=c(2,5,13,8,16,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,1,6,9,1,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,7,10,8,9, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

vetor_nome_variaveis_domicilio=c("V0001","V0002","V0011","V0300","V0010","V1001","V1002","V1003","V1004","V1006","V4001",
"V4002","V0201","V2011","V2012","V0202","V0203","V6203","V0204","V6204","V0205","V0206", "V0207","V0208","V0209","V0210","V0211","V0212","V0213","V0214","V0215","V0216","V0217", "V0218","V0219","V0220","V0221","V0222","V0301","V0401","V0402","V0701","V6529","V6530", "V6531","V6532","V6600","V6210","M0201","M2011","M0202","M0203","M0204","M0205","M0206", "M0207","M0208","M0209","M0210","M0211","M0212","M0213","M0214","M0215","M0216","M0217", "M0218","M0219","M0220","M0221","M0222","M0301","M0401","M0402","M0701","V1005")

dir_domicilio="C:/Users/Thiago.marques.censo/Desktop/Thiago/Microdados_Censo_2010/DOMICILIO_CENSO2010"

funcao_carga=function(diretorio,vetor_largura_fixa,vetor_variaveis) {

  setwd(diretorio)

  path <- diretorio files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="Amostra_Domicilios_11.txt")

  for(file in files){
    perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")

    assign(
      gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
      read_fwf(file,fwf_widths(vetor_largura_fixa,vetor_variaveis)))
    }
  }

funcao_carga(dir_domicilio,vetor_largura_domicilio,vetor_nome_variaveis_domicilio)
```

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no pacote [microdadosBrasil](https://github.com/lucasmation/microdadosBrasil)? Em especial função [`microdadosBrasil::read_CENSO()`](https://github.com/lucasmation/microdadosBrasil/blob/eef972f7504dfbbead098d84312608adaf4f31fb/R/import_wrapper_functions.R#L83). Pode te economizar muito trabalho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode salvar os data frames em uma lista.

Sua função ficaria:

```
funcao_carga=function(diretorio,vetor_largura_fixa,vetor_variaveis) {

  setwd(diretorio)
  lista <- list()

  path <- diretorio files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="Amostra_Domicilios_11.txt")

  for(file in files){
    perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")

    lista[[file]] <- assign(
      gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
      read_fwf(file,fwf_widths(vetor_largura_fixa,vetor_variaveis)))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Fica inacessível da mesma forma a lista, mas obrigado Rafael, foi boa a tentativa, eu descobri como faz, é só colocar :                                                         read_fwf(file,fwf_widths(vetor_largura_fixa,vetor_variaveis,envir = .GlobalEnv) , dessa forma ele copia o ambiente da função para o global, lhe agradeço mais uma vez.

Comment: Beleza então. Coloca essa descoberta como resposta e daqui a dois dias (se não me engano), aceite-a.

Comment: Já o fiz, muito obrigado!

Comment: o meu comentário foi no intuito de você colocar a sua descoberta como uma nova resposta, e não aceitar a minha, já que não surtiu efeito